# Overlapping Meteor publications

Tags: meteor, subscriptions, meteor-publications

I have a meteor app which has 2 publications for posts. One for all posts and one for featured posts. There are 2 featured posts - "Post 1" and "Post 4". I show featured posts on all pages, while i paginate all posts (including the featured posts) sorted by name. When i travel between pages, the data from the 2 publications get mixed up and show incorrect results.

Here is the code:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(page) {
  const skip = parseInt(page && page !== '' ? page : 0) * 3
  return Posts.find({}, {
    limit: 3,
    skip,
    sort: {
      name: 1
    }
  });
});

Meteor.publish('featured', function() {
  return Posts.find({
    featured: true
  }, {
    sort: {
      name: 1
    }
  });
});
```

On the client I am subscribing to both and displaying the data in 2 loops

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  const instance = this;
  instance.autorun(function() {
    instance.subscribe('posts', FlowRouter.getParam('page'))
    instance.subscribe('featured')
  });
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  posts() {
    return Posts.find({}, {
      limit: 3,
      sort: {
        name: 1
      }
    })
  },
  featured_posts() {
    return Posts.find({
      featured: true
    }, {
      sort: {
        name: 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

HTML template is as follows:

```
<template name="hello">
  <h2>Featured</h2>
  {{#each featured_posts}}
    {{> post}}
  {{/each}}
  <h2>Posts</h2>
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The problem is the data from the 2 subscriptions are getting mixed up in the display.

On page 1 it shows it correctly:

```
Page 1

Featured
  post 1
  post 4

All Posts
  post 1
  post 2
  post 3
```

but when I go to page 2

```
Page 2

Featured
  post 1
  post 4

All Posts  -- Should be
  post 1        post 4
  post 4        post 5
  post 5        post 6
```

It shows "post 1" inside the "posts" which is featured but shouldn't be on page 2. When I go to page 3, i see "post 1" and "post 4" but they should not be there.

I understand how the publications and subscriptions work and why this is happening - because the publications merges the dataset. I am wondering if there is a work around to keep them separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your pages correspond to pagination of your "All Posts" list. The "page" number is sent as your subscription parameter, so that you receive a short list of your posts.

The difficulty here is indeed that your Client collection does not have all your documents in hand (since you limit them in your `'posts'` publication), so you cannot use a similar `skip` logic as in the publication.

As proposed in Meteor Guide > [Paginating subscriptions](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#pagination), you could use the [`percolate:find-from-publication`](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/find-from-publication) Atmosphere package to easily retrieve the documents that come from your `'posts'` publication, and only them.

```js
// Server
FindFromPublication.publish('posts', function(page) {
  // Same logic
  const skip = parseInt(page && page !== '' ? page : 0) * 3
  return Posts.find({}, {
    limit: 3,
    skip,
    sort: {
      name: 1
    }
  });
});

// Client (no change in subscription)
Template.hello.helpers({
  posts() {
      return Posts.findFromPublication('posts', {}, {
        sort: {
          name: 1
        }
      });
    } // (no change in featured_posts)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [`observe` or `observeChanges`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe) so that the data being published can be isolated on the client. The docs can be intimidating but it's actually easier than it looks.

It's just a matter of creating a special client-side collection and then using the name of that collection in the observe callbacks. Notice that the client-side collection name, `"featured_posts"`, is used in the calls to `self.added`, `self.changed` and `self.removed` in the publication:

```
// client-side
const FeaturedPosts = new Mongo.Collection('featured_posts', {
  defineMutationMethods: false
});

// server-side
Meteor.publish('featured', function() {
    const self = this;

    const handle = collection.find(selector, opts).observe({
      added: function(doc) {
        self.added('featured_posts', doc._id, doc);
      },

      changed: function(newDoc, oldDoc) {
        self.changed('featured_posts', newDoc._id, newDoc);
      },

      removed: function(doc) {
        self.removed('featured_posts', doc._id);
      },
    });

    self.ready();

    self.onStop(function(err) {
      if (!err) {
        handle.stop();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I couldn't say for certain as I do not use collection helpers but considering that it's just registering a transform function, I would expect that it would work wherever transform functions work, i.e. with `observe`. 

From the docs.."Transforms are not applied for the callbacks of observeChanges or to cursors returned from publish functions."

Comment: Also...If you need to "join" data from other collections, keep in mind that you can perform whatever custom logic you need in the callbacks. Additionally, you can pass a transform function to find/findOne to override the collection-level transform.