# Update same client collection with different subscription

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I have a problem with subscriptions which should have fill same collection on the client with the different set of records. 
For example: 
I have a Books collection and two different publications:

1. `Meteor.publish(‘books’, () => Books.find({ status: { $ne: 3 } });`
2. publish  “booksForReservation” which is returning an array of books (books are filtered based on the reservation and some other data)

Problem occurs on the client, when I coming from one route to another. All Books collection are in the main component, and when I need those `booksForReservation` collection on the client is not updating with only that specific set of books.

I have subscribed on the client like:

```
Meteor.subscribe(‘booksForReservation’, reservationsIds);
let books = Books.find({}).fetch();
```

but I’m still getting all books collection displayed. when I have filtered Books collection on the client side with the same query used on the server, collection is updated. But then filtering it on the server doesn’t have any point.

How can I update same collection with different subscription?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006793/overlapping-meteor-publications/44007620#44007620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter collection on the client side with a query from the server. You subscribe to two publications, so on the client you will have data from both of them. The point of filtering collection on the server side is security. By doing it you won't publish any unwanted data to the client. You can read more about it here https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#specific-queries